# Obtener la cantidad de Registros que cumplen un criterio

Tags: laravel

Como Obtengo con laravel la cantidad de registros de la tabal alumnos cuyo campo zona es igual a un parámetro. Esta es la función en el controlador:**

```
    public function getNewNro(string $zona)
    {
        $cant = App\Models\Alumno::where('zona', $zona)->count();
        return $cant+1;
    }
```

y esta es la ruta

```
 Route::get('/alumnoCantXZona/{zona}','getNewNro');
```

Corro la app y pruebo en el thunder client de visual studio code con esto: GET   localhost:8000/api/AlumnoCantXZona/Metropolitana

me da como resultado un html completo cuando debería dar 1.

Las otras funciones andan todas. ¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: En la ruta que muestras no estas pasando el controlador al que corresponde la función, por lo que no creo que el proceso pase por la función que muestras. Revisa la documentacion de laravel para ver como se define la ruta https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#basic-controllers

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Si está indicado. Esta es la función completa: ```
Route::controller(AlumnoController::class)->group(function() {
    Route::get('/alumnos','index');
    Route::post('/alumno','store');
    Route::get('/alumno/{id}','show');
    Route::get('/alumnoDni/{id}','showByDni');
    Route::get('/alumnoExistNew/{id}','showOrNewByDni');
    Route::get('/alumnoCantXZona/{zona}','getNewNro');
    Route::put('/alumno/{id}','update');
    Route::delete('/alumno/{id}','destroy');
});
 ```

Comment: Ah, ok. Entonces te sugiero probar agregando el header `Accept: application/json` a la llamada. Tambien puedes agregar el header `Content-Type: application/json` a la respuesta retornando la función con `return response()->json([ 'data' => $cant+1 ]);`

Answer (score 0):

Ya corregí el error viendo bien como estaban escritos los otros métodos del controlador.
Lo tenía así:

```
$cant = App\Models\Alumno::where('zona', $zona)->count();
```

Le quite "App\Models" así:

```
$cant = Alumno::where('zona', $zona)->count();
```

y funcionó.

Comment: Es que la declaración de los modelos cuando no quieres u¡incluir las cabeceras se hace así `\App\Models\NombreModelo::metodos_a_ejecutar;`. Te faltaba el primer  \ . ¿Lo otro es, por qué retornas `$cant+1` si ya la función `count` te devuelve la cantidad?

Comment: Gracias por tu Respuesta. Muy buena aclaración. La razón por la que le sumo 1 es porque lo que necesita el front es el siguiente.